# Spring Quartz multiple concurrent job execution

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

We have a legacy monolithic application which uses **quartz 1.6.0** to run jobs. The problem is that each job runs 4 times, concurrently. Each job class extends `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean`.

We run the application on a Tomcat 6.

[Some](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/63151-quartz-tomcat-multiple-duplicate-job-executions) say it might be a tomcat issue, I've tried setting `autoDeploy="false"` and `deployOnStartup="false"`, but to no avail.

Some say the application-context is loaded multiple times, but when the app starts, I see all the things related to quartz only once.

```
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,222] INFO  - org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(100) | Initializing EHCache CacheManager
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,227] INFO  - org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(123) | Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,256] INFO  - org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.<init>(209) | Quartz Scheduler v.1.6.0 created.
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,257] INFO  - org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.initialize(141) | RAMJobStore initialized.
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,257] INFO  - org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(1208) | Quartz scheduler 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' initialized from an externally pr
ovided properties instance.
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,257] INFO  - org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(1212) | Quartz scheduler version: 1.6.0
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,257] INFO  - org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.setJobFactory(2065) | JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@bd65df9
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,258] INFO  - org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.startScheduler(626) | Starting Quartz Scheduler now
[2016-02-22 10:27:27,258] INFO  - org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(455) | Scheduler org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

I would like to fix the duplication problem, rather than synchronizing things in the code.

I watched the method call chain and realized that the QuartzScheduler constructor is called 4 times and the calls are like:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons()
...
AbstractApplicationContext.refresh()
ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext()
ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext()
```

The calls to initWebApplicationContext initiate from:

1. ContextLoaderListener
2. MessageDispatcherServlet x 2
3. DipatcherServlet

Here's the **web.xml** :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-gui</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-gui</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>....</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>...</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
    /WEB-INF/application-context-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Note**: *application-context.xml* includes the bean file which contains the QuartzSchedulerFactory bean.

Most definitely the problem is the misconfiguration of Spring. Why is the app-context loaded multiple times? What is the right way of configuring the Servlets and all?

Comment: Could you create a method with `@PostConstruct` annotation and a method body like this:  `System.out.println("Init!");` If you see the the output multiple times during you start your Application, then you have a problem with your Spring configuration, that causes the context to be loaded multiple times

Comment: That's a very good suggestion. I relied on the fact that I didn't see multiple log entries for the application context nor for quartz. I forgot to mention that JVisualVM showed 4 different quartz thread pools (4 * 10 threads) and 4 scheduler threads, so most definitely quartz is instantiated 4 times somehow. I'll get deeper into the code and come back after I find something.

Comment: Do you have 4 clusters?